# R error: cannot coerce closure to double

Tags: r, function, optimization

I'm trying to build an example of otimization for a friend of mine in R, but as said in the title I'm getting the following error. I saw another question with a similar answer, but it wasn't enlightening. I'd appreciate help, thanks.

> Error in optim(ll, method = "BFGS") : 
>   cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

```
dados <- rbinom(n = 40, size = 5, prob = 0.1)
cov <- rep(1, times = 40)
n <- 40

ll <-  function(k){
        fn_dados <- dados*cov - n*cov*(exp(cov*k)/(1 + exp(cov*k))) 
        loglike <- sum(fn_dados)
          return(loglike)
}

optim(ll, method = 'BFGS')
```

Comment: you have to give some initial values - should be `optim(inits, func, method)`. Your error is that R is trying to make ll the initial vals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were just missing some of the parameters, so you confused `optim()` about what you were passing into it.

```
optim(par=c(0),fn=ll, method = 'BFGS')
```

> ```
> $`par`
> [1] 400
>
> $value
> [1] -1581
>
> $counts
> function gradient 
>        2        2 
>
> $convergence
> [1] 0
>
> $message
> NULL
> ```